# Determine if Two Strings Are Close

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

i am trying to make a program that compares word1 strings with word2 string to occur only once

```
class Solution:
    def closeStrings(self, word1: str, word2: str) -> bool:
        word1 = [x.strip() for x in word1]
        word2 = [x.strip() for x in word2]
        update = False
        for x in word1:
            if(x in word2):
                update = True
                if(type(x) is str):
       
                    a = word1.index(x)
                    b = word2.index(x)
                    word1[a]=''
                    word2[b]=''
                else:
                    update = False
            else:
                update = False
                break
        
        return update
print(Solution.closeStrings(Solution,word1='a',word2='aa'))
```

Input

```
word1 = 'a',word2 ='aa'
```

Expected
 `Output = False`

Actual
`Output = True`

Comment: What is your logic to determine if two strings are close? Have you tried any [debugging](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Comment: What is the point of the test `if type(x) is str`? You are iterating over a list of strings at that point. How could `x` not be a string?

Comment: 1.) Typically, you define a class in order to make an instance of it. You don't call the methods like that. 2.) Why call x.strip() on every character? 3.) Why not simply count the characters in word2?

Answer (score 1):

1. `print(Solution.closeStrings(Solution,word1='a',word2='aa'))`

   You create a class in order to be able to create an instance of it. That way you don't need to pass `Solution` as the `self` parameter.
2. `word1 = [x.strip() for x in word1]`

   It looks like you expect to remove spaces. But you'll get a list of strings with empty strings for the spaces. That's not what you want. See the output of

   `print([x.strip() for x in "Hello world"])`
3. Your algorithm is way too complicated.

   You can simply count the occurrences of each character in word2:

```py
class Solution:
    def closeStrings(self, word1: str, word2: str) -> bool:
        for x in word1:
            if word2.count(x) != word1.count(x): return False
        return True


s = Solution()
print(s.closeStrings(word1='a',word2='aa'))
print(s.closeStrings(word1='abcb',word2='bcab'))
```

Comment: Your anser is correct and the person below your answer has understood it more correctly but I don't know why , the answer by @twister_void gets wrong when the Input  is 
'''
"a' and "aa"   ''' the output gets true which should be False. And when I replace your code then it gets wrong when the input is "' Input: word1 = "cabbba", word2 = "abbccc" '"
{ Output: true} expected but we get false

Answer (score 0):

Extending to other more solution answer by @Thomas Weller well explained by him

```py
class Solution:
    def closeStrings(self, word1: str, word2: str) -> bool:
        for i in word1:
            if i not in word2:
                return False
        for i in word2:
            if i not in word1:
                return False
        return True

    def closeStrings2(self, word1: str, word2: str) -> bool:
        if len(word1) != len(word2):
            return False
        if set(word1) != set(word2):
            return False
        return True

    def closeStrings3(self, word1: str, word2: str) -> bool:
        if len(word1) != len(word2):
            return False
        if sorted(word1) != sorted(word2):
            return False
        return True

print(Solution().closeStrings(word1="cabbba", word2="abbccc"))
print(Solution().closeStrings3(word1="cabbba", word2="aabbss"))
print(Solution().closeStrings3(word1="cabbba", word2="aabbss"))
```

Comment: You have 3 methods with the same name in one class. Is that intentional?

Comment: Your anser is correct and the person below your answer has understood it more correctly but I don't know why , the answer by @twister_void gets wrong when the Input is ''' "a' and "aa" ''' the output gets true which should be False. And when I replace your code then it gets wrong when the input is "' Input: word1 = "cabbba", word2 = "abbccc" '" { Output: true} expected but we get false